# Protractor function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, protractor

This is more of a JavaScript problem, but it's something that is trying to be implemented for the use of a Protractor test.

```
//fileA.js
element(by.id('page-element').getText().then(function() {
    var currentPremium = fileB.getSixMonthPremium(); // calls the function in fileB.js

    element(by.id('page-element').getText().then(function() {
        console.log(currentPremium); // prints undefined
        fileB.compareValue(currentPremium, ..., ...,);
    });
});


//fileB.js
this.getSixMonthPremium() = function() {
    element(by.id('full-premium').isDisplayed().then(function(displayed) {
        if (displayed) {
            element(by.id('full-premium').getText().then(function(currentPremium) {
                console.log('Current Premium - ' + currentPremium); // prints string of $XXX.xx
                return currentPremium; //seems to be returning undefined?
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When trying to use the variable `currentPremium` after it returns from the function call, it's always undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to using asynchronous calls with Javascript!

you will want to return a promise from the `getSixMonthPremium()` call, then continue work after that call comes back.

```
this.getSixMonthPremium() = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        element(by.id('full-premium').isDisplayed().then(function(displayed) {
            if (displayed) {
                element(by.id('full-premium').getText().then(function(currentPremium) {
                    console.log('Current Premium - ' + currentPremium); // prints string of $XXX.xx
                    resolve(currentPremium); //seems to be returning undefined?
                });
            }
        });
    })
});
```

then you will handle that promise by doing something like the below:

```
fileB.getSixMonthPremium().then(function(premium){
    ...handle premium
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something async/promise related but I couldn't quite find what I needed by searching Google. I need to get myself a JavaScript book or find some good online stuff :)